# How to pass a webrequest to localhost in PHP?

Tags: php, web, proxy

I have a public facing cgi interface. It supports only PHP. (Let's say: `domain.com/cgi/proxy.php`)

Then I have a java process (embedded web server) which listens to `localhost:9090`.

Is there a possibility to create a php script, which routes all requests from the cgi script to the java process on localhost. Something like a proxy in a script.

Should be like this:
`web -> public facing proxy.php -> local java process listening on 9090 -> return`

Answer (score 0):

You should use sockets in this case.
Look at PHP docs:

http://www.php.net/manual/it/book.sockets.php

And here some example:

http://www.php.net/manual/it/sockets.examples.php

You should connect to localhost on port 9090 (look at the example) and then send the data you want to be received by the java listener.